# Equivalent definitions of topological weak mixing

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, mixing

A dynamical system $f:X\to X$ is said to be topologically transitive if for any two nonempty open sets $U,V$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^{\circ n}(U) \cap V \neq \emptyset$. The following two definitions of topological weak mixing can be found in the literature:

1. $f$ is topologically weak mixing if $f\times f$ is topologically transitive on $X\times X$ (e.g [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/254a-lecture-7-structural-theory-of-topological-dynamical-systems/))
2. $f$ is topologically weak mixing if it has no non-constant continuous (with respect to the topology) eigenfunctions of the shift operator. (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_(mathematics)#Topological_mixing))

How are these definitions related? Can they be shown to be equivalent?

Comment: I suppose you want to add that $X$ is a (compact) metric or Hausdorff space and that the dynamical system map $f:X \to X$ is a continuous map.

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you understand as the eigenfunction of the shift operator? As I understand it, by an eigenfunction of a topological dynamical system an eigenfunction of the corresponding Koopman operator $T_f: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a complex linear subspace of $\mathbb{C}^X$. A canonical choice for $\mathcal{F}$ is the Banach space $C(X)$ of complex-valued continuous functions on $X$. But other spaces can be considered as well. However, the Eigenstructure of the Koopman operator may depend on the space $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: I forgot to mention how $T_f$ is defined. It maps $h \in \mathcal{F}$ to $h \circ f$. Certainly, we must assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under the action of $T_f$.

Answer (score 5):

Which are your regularity assumptions on $f$?

In general there are some subtle differences between the two definitions. If $X$ is a Baire space, then 1. implies (a slightly modified version of) 2. See on this Theorem 2.3 in [H.B. Keynes and J.B. Robertson, *Eigenvalue Theorems in Topological Transformation Groups*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-139-00/S0002-9947-1969-0237748-5/S0002-9947-1969-0237748-5.pdf).

In the same paper, Theorem 2.5 provides conditions making the two definitions basically equivalent. Theorem 2.8 shows instead a case of non-equivalence.

Notice that:

1. the mentioned paper concerns the more general setting of topological transformation groups;
2. the authors mean "almost everywhere" in a topological sense (= everywhere except on a meagre set);
3. they allow (unless differently specified) a meagre discontinuity set.

Comment: I'm confused, it looks like they allow a meager set of points of discontinuity, am I reading this wrong?

Comment: Yes, they say specifically "continuous transformation group" when continuity is assumed. In Theorem 2.3 meagre discontinuities are allowed. That's why I said "in general" and phrased the following with some caveats. I clarified the issue at the end of the answer.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte For the record, the function algebra that Keynes & Robertson use is the algebra of functions with "Baire property" (or "Baire measurable" functions, in other terminology); these are functions that are continuous modulo the $\sigma$-ideal of meager sets (in analogy with ergodicity, we don't get constancy everywhere). To me Tsirelson's account of this in Lecture 7 at https://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/Courses/MeasCategory/main.html is one of the clearest.